# Java file operations

Tags: java, parsing

I'm doing an assignment using Java, and our lecturers provided an example code for us. I'm unable to understand some of the code so can anyone explain?

```
    private long magic;
    private int minor;

    magic = file.readUnsignedShort() << 16 | file.readUnsignedShort();
    mnior = file.readUnsignedShort();
```

I don't understand why did he use "readUnsignedShort" for both of them and why did he add 
"<< 16 | file.readUnsignedShort()" for magic. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: ...what is the rest of the question like? Because I don't understand why they're going about this way either.

Comment: are you asking "what do those symbols mean?"  or are you asking "why would the lecturer use them here?"

Comment: This is a bit of supposition, but he wants an unsigned 32-bit integer. In Java (pre 8), the primitive types are always signed; therefore, it needs to be a long to get the unsigned range. As for the bit fiddling.... read a 16 bit number and shift left by 16 bits, then "add" another 16 bit number as the bottom 16 bits (the bitwise or) for a total of 32 bits.

Comment: Have you tied to open a book or read the specification ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short uses 16 bits, an int uses 32 and a long uses 64 bits.
Given this, there are not unsigned values in Java, so if the most significant bit is 1, it means the value is negative.

Splitting the code you have:

`file.readUnsignedShort()` <- reads 16 bits

`<< 16` <- moves them 16 positions "to the left", adding zeros (it's like multiply by 2^16)

`| file.readUnsignedShort();` <- in those 16 zeros, puts the next 16 bites read, using the OR operation, which works as follows:

```
xxxx0000 | 0000YYYY = xxxxYYYY
```

Answer (score 1):

This operation is like concat for bits.

short is 16 bit and integer is 32 bit long. Concatenating 2 short you will obtain a integer.

The << Operator stands for bitshift, in this way you are shifting the bits by sixteen positions.

Example:

```
NUMBER1 1111 1111 1111 1111
NUMBER2 0000 0000 0000 0000

NUMBER1 << 16 | NUMBER2 = 1111 1111 1111 1111  0000 0000 0000 0000
```

(thanks for hints)

Comment: In Java `int` is 32 bits and `long` is 64. (`short` is 16). But because they're all signed, if you want to use unsigned values, you have to put your numbers in a container that's one size bigger.

Comment: *Concatenating 2 integers you will obtain a long.* That is completely wrong. There is no operator that works on an int and produces a long. Your opening sentence is good though.

Comment: *In this way you are making a 64 bit number from 2x16* is equally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's start at the beginning.

1. `RandomAccessFile.readUnsignedShort()` reads 16 bits of information from the file, without interpreting it as a [2s complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).
2. So in the first line you do this: `<first two bytes of the file> << 16 | <third and fourth bytes of the file>`
3. `<<16` means shift the number left by 16 bits. For unsigned numbers, this is the equivalent of multiplying by 65536.
4. `|` means do a bitwise or. Because we know the first number was shifted, in our case this is equivalent to just adding the numbers.

So this is what it does, why it does it is anybody's guess. You should ask your teacher really, but my guess is that it might have something to do with the fact that this is the only way to read a 32-bit unsigned number via `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: Sure, on the condition that the value is stored in Big Endian.

Comment: Indeed. In fact my first idea was that the code was designed to convert little endian into big endian but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
magic = file.readUnsignedShort() << 16 | file.readUnsignedShort();
```

<< is bit shift operation

| is bitwise operation.

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).